# How do I do a repeated measures ANCOVA and a proportional odds regression in Python?

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to analyze some data in Python. Im unable to find a package to conduct the following tests in Python:

1. Repeated Measures ANCOVA
2. Proportional Odds Regression model

If anyone knows of a package I could use or tweak to perform these tests please do share. Thank you!

I have found tutorials for a repeated measures ANOVA but I have covariates that I need to include in my analysis which is why i need to perform the ANCOVA.